# From OS X CLI, read file and return only valid English dictionary words?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, cpu-word

#### Question

From an OS X command line, how can I check a list of strings from an input file (one string per line) and filter out the strings that are not valid dictionary words? For example, if the input were...

```
z3b8U
z6kgvhG3AkI
zealot
zealotry
```

...the output should return...

```
zealot
zealotry
```

#### Context

I'm trying to parse an input file (an ebook in text format) and get a list of the unique valid words. So far, I have the following to get all the unique strings in the file...

```
$ tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '\n' < input.txt | sort -u
```

I have the the `dict` command installed via Homebrew, but I haven't found an easy incantation that just filters out the invalid words and returns the valid ones.

Comment: I think there's dictionary of words in `/usr/share/dict/words.txt` or similar. You can grep all words in a corpus of text that occur in a dictionary of valid words with a command something like `grep -wF -f dictionary corpus`